# iOS Switch between Parse Server Connections with a button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, parse-server

Is it possible to initialize Parse configuration more than once in the app through a button?

The scenario is, Add a button inside a ViewController. When clicking, the app switches from my current live parse server to the testing server and vice versa.

Taking into consideration that the app cannot be killed and forced to restart as stated in apple documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. With Parse IOS SDK - Parse client is a singleton means that you can create only one instance of it. If you don't mind that users will need to close and open your app what you can do is to use **NSUserDefaults** there you can save the mode of the client (Test or Prod). Again... Users will need to manually restart the app.
2. **Without** Parse IOS SDK -  it can be done (without restarting the app) only if you will create a custom REST client that will work against Parse REST API. In this way you can create as many client as you want and each client will have it's own configurations.